# Final else if statement not running

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a basic tic-tac-toe type game in JavaScript. All of the spaces on the board work except for the last one, even though the x and y values are inside the rage of the if statement.

I don't know why the final else if statement is not working.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("tictactoe");
var cx = c.getContext('2d');
var turn;
var boardArray = [0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,
                  0,0,0];

function drawGameBoard(){
  cx.lineWidth = 20;
  cx.strokeStyle = "#888";
  cx.lineCap = "round";

  cx.beginPath();
  cx.moveTo(200,20);
  cx.lineTo(200,580);
  cx.moveTo(400,20);
  cx.lineTo(400,580);
  cx.moveTo(20,200);
  cx.lineTo(580,200);
  cx.moveTo(20,400);
  cx.lineTo(580,400);
  cx.stroke();
}

$("#tictactoe").click(function(e){
  var x = e.offsetX;
  var y = e.offsetY;
  checkPos(x, y);
});

function checkPos(x, y){
  alert(x +"+"+ y);
  if((x<190 && x>10) && (y<190 && y>10)){
    gamePiece(1);
  } else if((x<390 && x>210) && (y<190 && y>10)){
    gamePiece(2);
  } else if((x<590 && x>410) && (y<190 && y>10)){
    gamePiece(3);
  } else if((x<190 && x>10) && (y<390 && y>210)){
    gamePiece(4);
  } else if((x<390 && x>210) && (y<390 && y>210)){
    gamePiece(5);
  } else if((x<590 && x>410) && (y<390 && y>210)){
    gamePiece(6);
  } else if((x<190 && x>10) && (y<590 && y>410)){
    gamePiece(7);
  } else if((x<390 && x>210) && (y<590 && y>410)){
      gamePiece(8);
  } else if((x<590 && x>410) && (y<590 && y>410)){
      gamePiece(9);
  } else{
    //do nothing
  }
}

function gamePiece(pos){
  if(isEmpty(pos)){
    alert(pos);
    if(pos == 1){
      cx.clearRect(80,80,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(80,80,50,50);
    } 
    if(pos == 2){
      cx.clearRect(280,80,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(280,80,50,50);
    } 
    if(pos == 3){
      cx.clearRect(480,80,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(480,80,50,50);
    } 
    if(pos == 4){
      cx.clearRect(80,280,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(80,280,50,50);
    } 
    if(pos == 5){
      cx.clearRect(280,280,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(280,280,50,50);
    }
    if(pos == 6){
      cx.clearRect(480,280,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(480,280,50,50);
    } 
    if(pos == 7){
      cx.clearRect(80,480,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(80,480,50,50);
    } 
    if(pos == 8){
      cx.clearRect(280,480,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(280,480,50,50);
    }  
    if (pos == 9){
      cx.clearRect(480,480,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(480,480,50,50);
    }  
  }
}

function isEmpty(pos){
 if(boardArray[pos] == 0){
   return true;
 } else{
    return false;
  }
}

window.onLoad = drawGameBoard();
```

```css
body{
  padding: 0 auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper-parent{
  width: 100%;
}

.canvas-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.ctic{
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-parent">
  <div class="canvas-wrapper">
    <canvas id="tictactoe" class="ctic" width="600px" height='600px'>
    </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly does the `alert()` show when things don't work? (And you should probably use  `console.log()` instead.)

Comment: would love to see the use of `switch` instead of all those `if..else`'s just FYI

Comment: your board array is 0...8 - array indexes are 0 based ... you then use index 9 for the test against 0 ... but undefined !== 0, therefore your logic states that the place is already occupied

Comment: the fact is, `boardArray` is totally pointless, as it never gets updated anyway

Comment: the board array doesn't do anything yet the click function just sends a number to the other function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your "isEmpty" function like so:

```
function isEmpty(pos){
   // Array indexes start with 0 not 1
   // Also it is generally better to use strict equality in my opinion
   return (boardArray[(pos - 1)] === 0);
}
```

You have 9 items in your array which means the "pos" for the last item is "8" not "9"

Here is full snippet with that small change.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("tictactoe");
var cx = c.getContext('2d');
var turn;
var boardArray = [0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,
                  0,0,0];

function drawGameBoard(){
  cx.lineWidth = 20;
  cx.strokeStyle = "#888";
  cx.lineCap = "round";

  cx.beginPath();
  cx.moveTo(200,20);
  cx.lineTo(200,580);
  cx.moveTo(400,20);
  cx.lineTo(400,580);
  cx.moveTo(20,200);
  cx.lineTo(580,200);
  cx.moveTo(20,400);
  cx.lineTo(580,400);
  cx.stroke();
}

$("#tictactoe").click(function(e){
  var x = e.offsetX;
  var y = e.offsetY;
  checkPos(x, y);
});

function checkPos(x, y){
  alert(x +"+"+ y);
  if((x<190 && x>10) && (y<190 && y>10)){
    gamePiece(1);
  } else if((x<390 && x>210) && (y<190 && y>10)){
    gamePiece(2);
  } else if((x<590 && x>410) && (y<190 && y>10)){
    gamePiece(3);
  } else if((x<190 && x>10) && (y<390 && y>210)){
    gamePiece(4);
  } else if((x<390 && x>210) && (y<390 && y>210)){
    gamePiece(5);
  } else if((x<590 && x>410) && (y<390 && y>210)){
    gamePiece(6);
  } else if((x<190 && x>10) && (y<590 && y>410)){
    gamePiece(7);
  } else if((x<390 && x>210) && (y<590 && y>410)){
      gamePiece(8);
  } else if((x<590 && x>410) && (y<590 && y>410)){
      gamePiece(9);
  } else{
    //do nothing
  }
}

function gamePiece(pos){
  if(isEmpty(pos)){
    alert(pos);
    if(pos == 1){
      cx.clearRect(80,80,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(80,80,50,50);
    } 
    if(pos == 2){
      cx.clearRect(280,80,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(280,80,50,50);
    } 
    if(pos == 3){
      cx.clearRect(480,80,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(480,80,50,50);
    } 
    if(pos == 4){
      cx.clearRect(80,280,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(80,280,50,50);
    } 
    if(pos == 5){
      cx.clearRect(280,280,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(280,280,50,50);
    }
    if(pos == 6){
      cx.clearRect(480,280,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(480,280,50,50);
    } 
    if(pos == 7){
      cx.clearRect(80,480,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(80,480,50,50);
    } 
    if(pos == 8){
      cx.clearRect(280,480,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(280,480,50,50);
    }  
    if (pos == 9){
      cx.clearRect(480,480,50,50);
      cx.fillStyle = 'black';
      cx.fillRect(480,480,50,50);
    }  
  }
}

function isEmpty(pos){
   // Array indexes start with 0 not 1
   // Also it is generally better to use strict equality in my opinion
   return (boardArray[(pos - 1)] === 0);
}

window.onLoad = drawGameBoard();
```

```css
body{
  padding: 0 auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper-parent{
  width: 100%;
}

.canvas-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.ctic{
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-parent">
  <div class="canvas-wrapper">
    <canvas id="tictactoe" class="ctic" width="600px" height='600px'>
    </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The array isn't connected to anything the checkPos() function just looks if the click is inside a range and sends a number to another function

Comment: @Jake that number is used in the "gamePiece" function which then uses "isEmpty" to see if there is an item in that space on the board.  Since you are indexing the squares starting with 1 (1-9) you need to convert the position to the array index in order for you to properly evaluate the condition in "isEmpty"

Comment: Thought you were talking about the boardArray that didn't do anything

Comment: @Jake  np.  Happy coding.

Comment: also: `function isEmpty(pos) {return (boardArray[(pos - 1)] == 0);}`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are 0 based in Javascript... Your pos variable is 1 based...

Simply adjust your isEmpty function...

```
function isEmpty(pos){
 if(boardArray[pos - 1] == 0){
   return true;
 } else{
    return false;
  }
}
```